# Deconstructing types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I've defined the following type in Haskell:

```
data AE = Num Float
        | Add AE AE
        | Sub AE AE
        | Mult AE AE
        | Div AE AE
        deriving(Eq, Read, Show)
```

Now how do I deconstruct it? Specifically, how would I complete a function as follows:

```
testFunct :: AE -> something
testFunct expression
    | if type Num = do this
    | if type Add = then do this
    etc.
```

Also, how would I get the data out of the type? For instance, if I have `Sub AE1 AE2` how would I extract `AE2`?

Comment: bzn has given the right answer, but I thought it might also be worth mentioning that you might want to consider factoring this datatype; for example, you might write `data Op = Add | Sub | Mult | Div; data AE = Num Float | Bin Op AE AE`. This cuts down on repetition in the type, and may make certain functions on this type considerably more compact.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you're looking for is called 'pattern matching'. It let's you deconstruct types, by matching them against a given pattern. In your case, you could say:

```
testFunct (Num x) = ...
testFunct (Add a b) = ...
testFunct (Sub a b) = ...
```

You should work through a good haskell book, like [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) or Programming in Haskell.